# YouTube api request http 400 Issue with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I want to shoot channel videos using youtube api. First 10 minutes this code worked but now I am getting such error. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv29q.png)

***JavaScript***

```js
let fetchUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${API_KEY}&channelId=${channelId}`;
fetch(fetchUrl)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(resJson => console.log(resJson.items))
```

I want to list videos with "resJson.items" line.

Comment: If you look at the actual error it says: code 400, message: "API key expired. Please renew the API key"

Answer (score 1):

The api url looks ok but there is not enough information to tell what is wrong.
Two thinks to check:

1. Is the channel key in the request correct?
2. Is there any error message in API response?
   The easiest way to see it is to go to Network tab in developer tools in the browser - that would give you more information what is wrong with your request.